# How to update value in search box without repeating values

Tags: jquery

So here is the dilemma. 
1. I would like to use jquery to update the value in the input box based on the values that the user has chosen in the form. 
2. The form consists of a dropdown selection and 2 input boxes.
3. My code will update the select box values into the input BUT, keeps adding the values instead of replacing the old value with the new selection. 
4. Also, How do I get the values from the other inputs and add them to the string in the input box.

Here is a picture for clarity.

[image]

Here is the code I tried to get to work but it continues to add the value instead of replacing the old.

```
 $('#option2').on("change", function(){ 

    var dropdown = "Option2:" + $(this).val(); //Dropdown selection
    var searchbox = $('#searchbox').val(); //Value of searchbox
    var option3 = $('#option3').val(); //Value of input box 1

    if(option3 === ""){
        $('#searchbox').val(searchbox + " " + dropdown + " " + option3);
    }
    else{
        $('#searchbox').val(searchbox + " " + dropdown);
    }

});
```

I would also like to know how I can add the other 2 input box values(option3 & option4) to the search box as well, just like in the picture, since using .on("change", function) will only make changes with the dropdown selection.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build the option string fresh each time, reading the option values from `#option1`, `#option2`, etc., rather than reusing the string. Then it just naturally includes only a single value for each option:

```js
$(".search-param").on("change", function() {
  var params = $(".search-param")
    .map(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var val = $this.val();
      return !val ? undefined : this.id + ":" + val;
    })
    .get()
    .filter(function(v) { return v !== undefined; })
    .join(" ");
  $("#search-params").val(params);
});
```

```html
<select id="option1" class="search-param" size="1">
  <option value="">(none)</option>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>
</select>
<select id="option2" class="search-param" size="1">
  <option value="">(none)</option>
  <option>ay</option>
  <option>bee</option>
  <option>see</option>
</select>
<select id="option3" class="search-param" size="1">
  <option value="">(none)</option>
  <option>uno</option>
  <option>due</option>
  <option>tre</option>
</select>
<div>
  Search: <input type="text" id="search-params" size="60">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, do not add options to the searchbox value, but generate new value from input fields. But I think I see the problem here: user should be able to change options directly in search box... what to do than?

Comment: @skobaljic: That's a good point: On a `change` event (and/or possibly `input`) of the search box, they'll have to parse (which they'll need to do anyway, presumably, at some point) to isolate out free text vs. option text and apply the options to the selects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply T.J, It works great for the dropdown selection, replaces the value with each selection. How can I keep the search inbox text value without it being replaced by the select options?

Comment: @Stuckfornow: See the comment above: You parse it, retaining the bits that don't start with `optionX:`.